# Need list of specific contacts from account in custom object list view. How to set this up?

Tags: list-view, child-to-parent

We are set up where there is an account, and a 5-10 contacts that are related to the given account (they show up in the contact listview) and there is a custom object called proposals under contact. We need the same set of contacts that are in the account's contact listview displayed in a listview in the Proposal object which is a grandchild of the account. How to set it up not using any code?

Comment: Related lists are used to show the child records. That is standard behavior. If you want any customization than i think creating visualforce page is the only option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a way to do it declaratively, but it would involve creating a junction object between Contact and Proposal (since your Contacts for an Account will all be related to all Proposals under any of those Contacts) and building a very complex set of Process Builder and Flows automations to maintain the junction objects when Contacts or Proposals change.

You'd need at least one Process on Contact and one on Proposal, each of which would call an autolaunched Flow that would query down from the Account to get associated Contacts and their Proposals, then create appropriate junction objects and remove any that are invalidated. It's doable, but frankly I wouldn't do it declaratively - at that level you're practically just writing code with Flow blocks anyway.

It would be less work to create a very simple Visualforce page or Lightning component to surface at the Proposal level, which would query the Contacts for the Proposal Contact's Account and generate a list dynamically.